# Not able to close a modal window while clicking close(X) button in JQuery UI Dialoge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').on('click', function(){
    console.log('inside close');
    $('.ui-dialog').dialog("close");
    });
```

I used the above code still it is not closing the modal window even control is not going to the function.
Can you guys help me where I am missing the point?

Comment: Can you see the `console.log`?

Comment: Control is not going to the function means console log is not printing.

Comment: Please show your html content where you implemented UI dialogue

Comment: You added that part after I asked the question !

Comment: $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
         resizable: false,
         height: "auto",
         width: 400,
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
           Cancel: function() {
             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
           },
           Ok: function() {
             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
           }
         }
       });
This is the code i am using to close the above code to close is working fine for the remaining buttons Cancel, Ok but not working for Close(X) button.

Comment: Actually I forgot to add, while editing it self you given a comment. 
I don't think it's wrong. If you feel any wrong sorry for it. @Mehdi

Comment: Oh, sorry @Mehdi.
it's my mistake happened in 2nd comment. It leads some another meaning. 
"Control is not going to the function I mean console log is not printing."
edited statement.

Comment: @Sandeepsandy Don't worry, do you mean the plugin has issue, or you want to manually close the modal _via your own code_?

Comment: Actually I tried entire code given by plugin in a separate file then it is working fine. But while working combine with my project it is creating issues. So i want to manually close the modal window. @Mehdi

Comment: I recommended to find the cause of issue, btw, did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('.ui-button').click();
```

I tired it on [jQuery UI Dialog Demo page](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/default.html) and works.

Also you can see that in action @
[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/m-dehghani/pen/bwgJAg)

Comment: Thank you for your time, I tried it is working fine. But due to some project issues it is not working. I will figure it out.

Comment: NP, you may check the `console` or try to added `console.log` inside `jQuery UI` source code, to find the cause of problem. btw if you can provide some testcase, maybe we can help.